# Programmatically check if js code is ie11 compatible (automated test)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, automated-tests

I have a js script which should support ie11.
I would like to set up an automated test - in which it checks the code and alerts if the script contains any method which is not supported in ie11.

I found an npm lib called "eslint-plugin-compat" - but it doesn't seem to catch all unsupported methods.

Does someone know/used a library or has any other solution for this?

I would like for this automated test to fail when someone used the method Object.assign(), which is not supported in ie11

Answer (score 0):

Babel is the best solution for your project

Babel converts ECMAScript 2015+ code into a backwards compatible version of JavaScript in current and older browsers or environments, [click here for details](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/)

So you can configure your project to use babel and you can write your code in es5+ even if the target browsers are not supporting some features of ECMA, Babel will compile your code and give you a js files working on your target browsers that you have to configure in babel.config.js like:

```
 const presets = [ [ 
"@babel/env", { targets: 
{ edge: "17", 
firefox: "60", 
ie: "11",
chrome: "67", 
safari: "11.1", }, 
useBuiltIns: "usage", }, ], ];

 module.exports = { presets };
```

[More details here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/usage)

With babel you will not care about the js code you write if it will work for some browser or not, you will write your js code with the latest features of es you will use and babel will do the work to let your project working well in your target browsers